# jquery data tables server side processing in python django

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, datatables

im displaying my data using jquery data tables so its taking much time to load  so i hav to porivide  server side processing how can i do that any suggitions???

```
enter code here
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "../server_side/scripts/server_processing.php"
    } );
} );
```

Comment: how many rows are you displaying? it just should not take that long. If server side is set to true, then DataTables will pass back any search criteria used and row number and offset so you can figure out what page you are on. Its up to you to figure out how to grab the appropriate data from the database and display it.

Comment: many records of enquiery form  from my website, when im opening in the server its tacking much time to load... so thinking to cange it to server side , bt i never did it before...with tht ajax source it wil all or with simlpy addi "serverSise" = true;  ???  @Bindrid

Comment: thanks for responding @Bindrid

Comment: With serverSide:false (default) , you pass all the data at once. DataTables figures out how many rows, how many rows per page, what search is being applied, what page you are on and just about everthing else.  When serverside:true dataTables send the parameters described at https://datatables.net/manual/server-side  and you have to write the server side code to handle that info and send back a single page of data based on that.

Comment: look at the php tab here for a simple example https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html

Comment: thanks for the links..but thts serverside script in php bt hw acn i change it to python

Comment: https://datatables.net/development/server-side/python_mysql is python. It is for an outdated version of DataTables but the back end should not be that different

Comment: thank you so much for the help......@Bindrid